# How to turn a data list into a reference table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have the following (csv like extract):

```
groupname  origin    destination  speed winner
client1    paris    newyork      100 bob
client1    paris    tokyo        200 joe
client1    paris    london       100 
client1    tokyo    paris        213 kok
client1    tokyo    newyork      234 lok
client1    newyork  paris        233
```

How would I turn the above into this speed table for Client1?

```
         paris    newyork    london    tokyo
paris             100, bob        100       200, joe
newyork  233
london
tokyo    213, kok      234, lok
```

I am not sure how to call this, but this is very similar to the distance tables on older maps.

Because I want to report the value in my result table, I am not sure pivot table is the right option.
Thanks!

Comment: My immediate reaction to seeing that problem is that it could be solved with VBA. Have you considered using VBA?

Comment: as you have guessed I am pretty noob with excel and so I am with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In. It takes a few steps to get there and a bit of coding in the Power Query language (M) to call the Table.Pivot function (it's not exposed in the Power Query UI).

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Pivot rows into columns.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically my technique was to add a calculated column to combine the Speed and Winner (e.g. 100, bob), and remove the original Speed and Winner columns.  Then I used the Table.Pivot function to generate a column for each unique value in the destination column.

The documentation for Table.Pivot is here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/table-pivot-HA104111995.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104122363

Another example of using Table.Pivot is here:

http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/pivoting-data-in-power-query/

Comment: This is great, I did not know PowerQuery existing on Excel. I'll make sure I use it even more in the future!

Comment: It is quite new, but I'm very impressed with it so far.  They have struck an elegant balance between easy wizards and coding power.

Comment: The latest version of Power Query now exposes the Table.Pivot command as a button. I've just updated my demo file to make use of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very quickly with a pivot table. Just select all your data (column headers included) and click `Pivot Table` on the `Insert` ribbon. Once you have selected a location for your pivot table, just drag and drop your fields in the Pivot Table Fields List as follows:

```
Report Filter: groupname
Row Labels: origin
Column Labels: destination
Values: speed ('Sum of' is what you want)
```

And that just about does it. You just have to select `client1` from your report filter located above the pivot table.

[image]

You can also change the pivot table settings so that the Grand Totals row and column are not shown.

Comment: This is great for numerical values but how can it be done for string value?